# How to insert values from variables into database (Eg. $closedb,$profitandloss)

Tags: php, sql

i just wanna know whats the proper method to insert a value from a variable into a table in DB. Am i doing it the wrong way?

```
**$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `trade_history1` (user_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit,dateclose,close,profitandloss)
    SELECT user_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit, 'null','null','null'**
    FROM `opentrades`
    WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
    $mysqli-> query("UPDATE trade_history1 set dateclose=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
    **$mysqli-> query("UPDATE trade_history1 set close='{$closedb}' WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);**
    **$mysqli-> query("UPDATE trade_history1 set profitandloss='{$profitandloss}' WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);**

    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `opentrades` WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);
```

Comment: WHat is your question?  What is the problem with your sample code?

Comment: How do i insert variable into database? i tried the method above and it appears to be not working

Comment: People on the web cannot (generally) read minds, what variable are you trying to insert into what table?

Comment: $closedb,$profitandloss

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE trade_history1 set profitandloss='" . addslashes($profitandloss) . "' WHERE `trade_id` = '" . addslashes($trade_id) . "'");
```

I don't see any declarations of these variables.

Comment: So my answer shows you how to insert value from PHP variable into query. If it isn't what you need, so I don't know, what you mean.

Comment: You have bad syntax.

`INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('Hello', 'World', 'Yeah')`

Comment: Dude.i need to select from another table i cant do it that way .

Comment: $query = $mysql->query("SELECT...")

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

echo $row['column'];